Help on Alon and Spencer problem on probability of $\epsilon$-regularity in a random graph
Problem (Alon and Spencer, 17.6.1):


Show that for every fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ and $0 < p < 1$ there is an $m_0 = m_0(\varepsilon, p)$ so that for every $n > 2m > m_0$, the probability that two fixed disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, each of size $m$, of the random graph $G(n, p)$ do not form an $\varepsilon$-regular pair is smaller than $\varepsilon$.


(original at https://i.sstatic.net/DvIm2d4E.png)
I translated the problem into mathematical language and we need to prove the existence of $m_0$ such that $$\text{Pr}(\text{Pr}(|d(A, B) - d(X, Y)| \le \epsilon \text{ for random } X \in A \text{ and } Y \in B) < 1) < \epsilon$$
Note: $d(A, B)$ refers to the [density of two disjoint subsets of a graph] definition used in Szemeredi's Regularity Lemma. Read Alon and Spencer's section 17.5 for more info.
However, I am having a hard time resolving the left hand side expression in terms of the variables given. I don't know how to find the inner probability. I also tried rewriting the inner condition as $\mathbb{E}[|d(A, B) - d(X, Y)|] < \epsilon$, thinking that it might help – but I didn't find it easy to compute because $d(A, B)$ and $d(X, Y)$ are fractions, and it's not easy to find the expected value of a fraction.
Please give me a hint on how to proceed.
EDIT: I randomly stumbled upon Markov's Inequality, which states that $P[X \ge a] \le \frac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{a}$. This seemed promising, but then again I realized that it forces us to find $\mathbb{E}[d(A, B) - d(X, Y)]$ : - (

I've converted the text in the image to MathJax. OP, please check to make sure the content has been converted correctly. If you feel that the image contains something that cannot be captured in MathJax, you may revert, but otherwise, it's better for the search function if we keep it in MathJax.

Thanks for doing that!

You've translated the problem from words to math notation incorrectly -- the inner "probability" shouldn't be there. The definition of $\varepsilon$-regular is that for every $X \subseteq A$ and $Y \subseteq B$ (with $|X| \geq \varepsilon |A|$ and $|Y| \geq \varepsilon |B|$), we have $|d(X,Y)-d(A,B)| \leq \varepsilon$. Thus we want to show that the probability that "there exists $X \subseteq A$ and $Y \subseteq B$ (with $|X| \geq \varepsilon |A|$ and $|Y| \geq \varepsilon |B|$) with $|d(X,Y)-d(A,B)| > \varepsilon$" is very small.
The typical approach to this is to perform a union bound. Given $X$ and $Y$, estimate the probability that $|d(X,Y)-d(A,B)| > \varepsilon$, which is easy to do with the Chernoff bound: the probability that either $d(X,Y)$ or $d(A,B)$ differ from $p$ by a constant factor is exponential in $m^2$. The number of $X,Y$ you have to take a union bound over is at most exponential in $m$, so the union bound will be successful. Of course, sorting out all of these details precisely takes time and is a good exercise.

I agree that I made the mistake of ignoring the $|X| \ge \epsilon |A|$ and $|Y| \ge \epsilon |B|$ part, but how is the inner probability incorrect altogether?
My idea was that given a graph, and two sets $A$ and $B$ in the graph, randomly pick subsets $X,Y$ of $A,B$. If the probability that $|d(A,B)-d(X,Y)| \le \epsilon$ is less than $1$, then it means that there exists a pair $X,Y$ so that the property is not satisfied and hence $A, B$ are not $\epsilon$-regular.
Now, the probability that this condition itself occurs should be less than $\epsilon$ as instructed by the problem statement.

Rather, the inner probability is unnecessary. The inner probability being less than $1$ is equivalent to "there exists $X$ and $Y$ such that $|d(X,Y)-d(A,B)| \leq \varepsilon$, assuming the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is not chosen too poorly. But why are we even choosing $X$ and $Y$ randomly to begin with? This is not in the definition of $\varepsilon$-regular. The existential statement is simpler than the probability statement (since you don't have to specify the distribution of $X$ and $Y$), and we can use the union bound to bound the probability this existential statement holds.
